# Need to put images next to list

Tags: html, css

I'm redoing a online textbook for a professor, and I need to have an image next to the listed points describing what's in the image. Code currently looks like this:

HTML:

```html
<div class="flex.container">
  <div id="flextext">
    <ul>
      <li> Hairpins (eg. <em>Borellia</em>) - Normally linear chromosomes
        contain inverted repeats at each end, which are capable of forming
        hairpin loop by intra-strand base pairing. When the leading strand
        from an internal replication origin arrives at the hairpin, the
        hairpin allows the template strand to be replicated in much the same
        way as a circular plasmid, such that the leading strand is
        redirected to "follow behind" the lagging strand. Thus, there is
        always a polymerase complex upstream from each lagging strand.</li>
      <br>
      <li> Invertrons (eg. Streptomyces) - Linear chromosomes contain
        inverted repeat units at both ends. Inverted repeats are bound by
        terminal proteins (TP) which bind to the 5' end of the repeats. The
        terminal proteins themselves act as primers, binding DNA polymerase.
        The first nucleotide to be added to the template is covalently bound
        to the TP, and the chain is elongated by further addition of
        nucleotides to the 3' end of that nucleotide. </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="fleximage"> <img src="LinearProk.png"> </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.flex-container {display:flex; flex-direction: row; align-items:center;}
#flextext {width:50%;}
#fleximage {width:50%;}
```

The page still has the image below the list. I've added width properties to each box because I thought perhaps they were too large to go next to each other - no luck. I did originally try flexbox without naming/defining flextext or fleximage, but noticed that the list items spanned the whole width of the page. I found that I had to define width for it to leave space for the image.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or what I need to add. From what I understand, since each item in the parent div is its own div, they should just line up in a row like happy ducks.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You have a typo: `<div class="flex.container">` should be `<div class="flex-container">`. That's it.

Comment: Also don't use `<br>` for spacing...that's what margins and padding are for. This is especially true in `ul` where it makes your HTML invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set wrong class name change to  `<div class="flex-container">`

```css
.flex-container {
display:flex; 
 flex-direction: row; 
align-items:center;
   
}
      #flextext {width:50%;}
      #fleximage {width:50%;}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
      <div id="flextext">
        <ul>
          <li> Hairpins (eg. <em>Borellia</em>) - Normally linear chromosomes
            contain inverted repeats at each end, which are capable of forming
            hairpin loop by intra-strand base pairing. When the leading strand
            from an internal replication origin arrives at the hairpin, the
            hairpin allows the template strand to be replicated in much the same
            way as a circular plasmid, such that the leading strand is
            redirected to "follow behind" the lagging strand. Thus, there is
            always a polymerase complex upstream from each lagging strand.</li>
          <br>
          <li> Invertrons (eg. Streptomyces) - Linear chromosomes contain
            inverted repeat units at both ends. Inverted repeats are bound by
            terminal proteins (TP) which bind to the 5' end of the repeats. The
            terminal proteins themselves act as primers, binding DNA polymerase.
            The first nucleotide to be added to the template is covalently bound
            to the TP, and the chain is elongated by further addition of
            nucleotides to the 3' end of that nucleotide. </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="fleximage"> <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/736230/pexels-photo-736230.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=300"> </div>
    </div>
```